# Pygame Sprite Collision only giving True

Tags: python, pygame, sprite, collision-detection, collision

I want the code to detect the collision between a rock and a player. But somehow, the program detects a collision the WHOLE TIME. I tried debugging it and I tried looking for solutions to this problem but with no success. It is just me or is this very common.

Maybe it is the rectangle size? When I try doing everything I can, the problem just continues. Try out the code yourself. Help me!

Please answer!

Code:

```
from random import *
import time
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import sys
pygame.init()

class character(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, image):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.image = image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect();

    def checkCollision(sprite1, sprite2):
        if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(sprite1, sprite2):
            print(pygame.sprite.collide_rect(sprite1, sprite2))

pressed_left = False
pressed_right = False
pressed_up = False
pressed_down = False
x_speed = 1
y_speed = 1
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))

playerskin = pygame.image.load('Player1_Skin.png').convert_alpha()
rockskin = pygame.image.load('Player2_Skin.png').convert_alpha()

player = character(20, 20, playerskin)
rock = character(400, 400, rockskin)

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
            sys.exit()        
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                pressed_left = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                pressed_right = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                pressed_up = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                pressed_down = True
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                pressed_left = False
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                pressed_right = False
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                pressed_up = False
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                pressed_down = False

    if pressed_left:
        player.x -= x_speed
    if pressed_right:
        player.x += x_speed
    if pressed_up:
        player.y -= y_speed
    if pressed_down:
        player.y += y_speed

    screen.fill((0, 255, 0))

    screen.blit(player.image, (player.x, player.y))
    screen.blit(rock.image, (rock.x, rock.y))

    print(bool(pygame.sprite.collide_rect(rock, player)))
    #rock.checkCollision(player)

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rects are not moving, as they are based on the image, which you are offsetting when you blit them to the screen.

You need to copy the image rect at initialization (you're already doing this), and then use rect.move to represent the bounding box at each entity's position.

Comment: I added rect.move after blitting them to the screen every single time. It still doesn't work.

Comment: P.S. I tried rect.move_ip and got only false and no true. Sorry if I am quite bad, I am a very new programmer.

Comment: @TinyNerd_Programming - `collide_rect` was returning False?  I thought it was always returning True?  Have you tried using print statements on each of the rects' X and Y to verify everything is working as intended?

Comment: No no, rect.move_ip made it turn false only.

Comment: @TinyNerd_Programming Have you tried using print statements on each of the rects' X and Y to verify everything is working as intended?  What values is it printing for each rect?

Comment: It is printing out the coordinates that it has to print normally.

Comment: I tried printing out the character's positions but I have no idea how to get the positions of the rects themselves.

Comment: @TinyNerd_Programming It's been a while since I tried, but can you access the "topleft" attribute?

Comment: I tried print(player.rect) and print(rock.rect) and the program printed both rectangles at coordinates 0, 0.

Comment: @TinyNerd_Programming Can you post your code?  I'm assuming you're calling `player.rect.move_ip` and `rock.rect.move_ip`?

Comment: I found the solution! I had to use move_ip to move the rects each and every time I pressed a key. And I also had to make the rects start at the positions where the characters had to start. Thanks anyways for your help! I appreciate it!